# Transferir objetos entre fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Boa noite.. sou iniciante em Java Android e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação pra ser utilizada na máquina de cartão de crédito da Gertec. Porém a minha aplicação terá outras formas de pagamento alem de cartão (dinheiro, cheque, nota prazo).
Estou fazendo a parte da venda com dinheiro, onde na tela principal (fragment) tem um recycleview com as formas de pagamento. Ao usuário clicar na forma de pagamento dinheiro eu exibo pra ele um fragment dialog com um campo onde ele poderá informar o valor que está pagando. 
Segue o código de como estou utilizando

```
rcvFormaPagamento.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getContext(), rcvFormaPagamento, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            FormaPagamento formaPagamento = listaFormaPagamento.get(position);
            FormaPagamentoBo formaPagamentoBo = new FormaPagamentoBo(getContext());
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    //TODO Finalização da venda em Dinheiro
                    formaPagamentoBo.FinalizarVenda(formaPagamento);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //TODO Finalização da venda em Cartão de Crédito
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), formaPagamento.getDescricao(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //TODO Finalização da venda em Cartão de Débito
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), formaPagamento.getDescricao(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //TODO Finalização da venda em Nota a Prazo
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), formaPagamento.getDescricao(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //TODO Finalização da venda em Boleto
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), formaPagamento.getDescricao(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Funcionalidade não implementada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
```

Por questão de organização, eu criei uma classe pra tratar cada forma de pagamento.
Exemplo da classe FormaPagamento chamando a classe Dinheiro

```
 @Override
public void FinalizarVenda(FormaPagamento entidade) {
    switch (entidade.getCodigoFormaPagamento()) {
        case 1:
            Dinheiro dinheiro = new Dinheiro();
            dinheiro.setDescricao(entidade.getDescricao());
            dinheiro.setCodigoFormaPagamento(entidade.getCodigoFormaPagamento());
            dinheiro.setTotal(entidade.getTotalFormaPagamento());
            dinheiro.setPago(entidade.getTotalFormaPagamento());
            dinheiro.setTroco(0);
            DinheiroBo dinheiroBo = new DinheiroBo(context);
            dinheiroBo.Pagar(dinheiro);
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
    }
}
```

Classe dinheiro por sua vez, chamando dialogfragment

```
    @Override
public void Pagar(Dinheiro entidade) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentFormaPagamentoDinheiro fragmentFormaPagamentoDinheiro = FragmentFormaPagamentoDinheiro.newInstance(entidade);
    fragmentFormaPagamentoDinheiro.show(fragmentManager, "frag_forma_pagamento_dinheiro");
}
```

Nesse dialogframent eu tenho um botão de confirmar que deverá dar continuidade ao processo de pagamento.

Até aí tudo bem, o problema é quando ele confirma o valor e preciso dar continuidade na finalização da venda, não sei como fazer pra pegar esses dados que foi informado e juntar com os outros dados da venda para poder dar continuidade. Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda
Obrigado

Comment: Olá @willian bem vindo ao StackOverflow, por favor adicione alguns trechos de código para que possamos entender como está executando este processo e encontrar uma solução, sugiro que leia [mcve]

Comment: Opa @LucasDuete, editei a pergunta. Obrigado

Comment: Vê se esse conteúdo te ajuda: https://www.androidpro.com.br/blog/desenvolvimento-android/fragments/